# match the names

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables. CustomersTable and BusinessDirectory
Both tables have a column called businessName.
my CustomerTable has a columns cid, customerID, businessName 
my BusinessDirectory table has columns  bdid, businessName, getID

I want to update the getID field in BusinessDirectory table by customerID in CustomerTable where the business name matches in CustomerTable. Hence I did this query

```
update BusinessDirectory INNER JOIN CustomerTable ON CustomerTable.businessName = BusinessDirectory.businessName set BusinessDirectory.getID = CustomerTable.customerID;
```

which updates the records fine as long as the records match 100%. There are some records where there is a little typo and stuff
like I have a business name General Contractors Inc in one table and the other table has it as General Contractors. As you can see its missing Inc, so it doesnt match. What can I do to get best possible matches.
Thanks

Comment: The first thing to do is to exactly describe how you want to match (i. e. get the specification right). If you have done this, then you can put it into an algorithm.
To state it differently: How exactly do you want to decide if the names match or not? One starts with the other or vice versa?

Comment: I want to match first few letters before the space.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but it is not particularly safe:

```
UPDATE BusinessDirectory, CustomerTable 
SET BusinessDirectory.getID = CustomerTable.customerID
WHERE BusinessDirectory.businessName Like
Left(CustomerTable.businessName,InstrRev(CustomerTable.businessName," ")) & "*"
```